# how to change Label text to last value from MySql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

So i got a database senzor with user senzor and pass password 
the database looks like this
[database screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM941.jpg)

i want to display last value from "temp" in a text label in c# program when i click a "REFRESH" button.
i`m using visual studio 2013 C# for the program.

PS the text label will automaticly change value when i click the REFRESH button and will remain unchanged untill i press the REFRESH button again.

thanks in advance ,

Johnny M

Comment: It will be good if you can add details on what mechanism you're using to read from the database and sort order

Comment: i`m sorry i`m newbie to this .. So i`m using the visual studio Windows forms , and the mysql is based on XAMPP server, and i want the last inserted value ... i gues the timestamp is the sorting order.

Answer (score 0):

Order descending, then use the limit to return the last row -- now in the first position!

```
    String query =  @"SELECT temp
        FROM TableName
        ORDER BY Id DESC
        LIMIT 1";

     string connString = "Server=localhost; Database=myDatabaseName; 
 Trusted_Connection=Yes";

   SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);


DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Do your table mappings if any. And then call `da.Fill(ds, "issuedBooks");`

```
    Label.Text = ds;
```

you can use this code inside button "REFRESH"

Comment: and how do i put this in label ?

Comment: I will Edit the answer

Comment: i get error when i try to build it .. <code>        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String result =  (SELECT temp FROM senzor ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1);



Label8.Text = result;
        } </code>

Comment: Feras .. i get this error..Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'string'

Comment: You can add Label.Text = ds.Tostring();